# Are these logos too similar?

Tags: logo, critique

Hi there after finishing the logo for a sports clothing brand I thought it was too similar to something and I went looking and found this USAF logo, what do you think? The Bulldozer logo is meant to look like a bull, and the USAF logo is wings.
Are they too similar to use?

[image] -----**VS**----- [image]

Comment: Side-stepping the actual question, although the etymology of "bulldozer" does go back to "bull", if you say "bulldozer" to somebody, they think "earth-moving equipment", not "male cattle."

Comment: Arc the bulldozer text around like the usaf text to make it more similar :P Honestly, I dont think the usaf owns shapes. I personally think your logo is fine, but im not a lawyer.

Comment: Honestly, I think it looks a bit like a Romulan Bird-Of-Prey starship...

Comment: To me it doesn't look like a bull or a bulldozer ...but it does resemble, a bit, the AF logo.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simple answer...no. While they share similar overall form, they are clearly different both in concept and execution.

Unfortunately, neither Matt nor myself are correct. It's really an opinion based question.

Will the airforce sue you over your logo? Highly unlikely. For starters, I doubt the two companies are competing. I don't see any intentional attempt to mislead the consumer. The concepts are quite different. I could go on.

Answer (score 8):

For me when I look at your logo at a glance and from a distance I would say yes.  If I look at your logo while driving down a road when its on a sign and not reading what it says it would remind of the air force.    Look at them from a distance:

[image]

Some ideas to improve it:

- Change the direction
- Fill instead of outline some areas
- change from a bird like appearance

The bigger question you should ask yourself is how does that symbol reflect Bulldozer Aesthetics.  Also, you spelled it Asthetics when spell checker tells me it should be Aesthetics