# Do these logos look similar?

Tags: logo

[image]

[image]

I wanted to know if our company logo looks similar to this companies logo.

To help get a better answer to this, we work with apparel and this company also sells apparel.

Comment: Yes, it does look similar. Especially if I take a harder look at it... It's like someone took Emerica's logo as the base of this logo and changed things here and there to make it look different. Would you get in trouble for that... I mean Apple did patent a rectangle with round corners, so anything is possible. As someone who is _not a lawyer_, I'd say no.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should happen if a logo I made is similar to another?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92460/what-should-happen-if-a-logo-i-made-is-similar-to-another)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. They look slightly similar, but when you ask "if we would get in trouble", this is ultimately a legal question, and I'm not willing to give legal advice since I'm not a lawyer. Ask your lawyer instead.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the welcome :)! And I see I understand now. But thank you for the advice!

Comment: To me, it simply looks like the symbol was merely flipped upside down at first glance, and then the color changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They kind of do look similar, but also with enough differences. If you look hard enough i'm sure you can find other similar logos in half an hour. Not sure what the legal base is for this in the US, which may not be very flexible on the similarity factor.

Comment: Yeah I see what you’re saying. I’ve been trying to ask a lot of people near where I live and everyone said they could see a little similarity if I asked but overall they said they could tell the companies apart.

Answer (score 0):

They're both Nike swooshes with additional Adidas stripes.
[They're not, but you could see how if someone really wants to stretch a point, they can...]

Comment: This seems better suited as a comment than an answer to me

Comment: tbh, as the question itself ought to be closed as being opinion-based, I just thought I'd get my 2¢ in before it was. There is no answer we can provide here - an actual answer would need lawyers.