# It was never my intention but my startup logo looks similar to Google Colab's logo. Should I change it?

Tags: logo, copyright, trademark

[image]
[image]

My startup's logo (left) looks very similar to Google Colab's logo (right). I don't think it would cause any confusion as my company operates in a completely different market. However, I am getting a few "looks like Google Colab's logo" from my friends. What do you guys think? Should I change it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should happen if a logo I made is similar to another?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/92460/what-should-happen-if-a-logo-i-made-is-similar-to-another) -- Even if you *might* get away with it.... why on Earth would you want your logo looking like another companies? It simply dilutes *your* brand entirely, especially against a titan such as Google. To be fair.. neither mark is very creative or original.. so if it were me, I'd strive to be a bit better than either of them.

Comment: Yes, I feel you should change it. I Googled "CO" logo and and when I scrolled 1 page, I found 2-3 sample icons/logos which are very similar to your logo (shapes). So it looks very common.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't matter. I think it depends on how hard you are branding your stuff. Branding is not just the logo, so it can still work.
What bothers me is the lack of geometry in your design ... those are letters with slight oval but it's so slight that it looks like a mistake.

Comment: "It doesn't matter".  But it will matter if google takes the OP to court for copyright/trademark infringement. Even if such a case were to fail, the legal costs alone could cripple a start-up business. Can you personally guarantee that this will absolutely not happen?  Are you a legal professional?  Are you giving legal advice here? Yes the downvote is mine, sorry.